# Named dynamic update simulation

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dynamic-dns

I'd like to manually change some entries in a Bind server via the dynamic update. I couldn't find any specific tool to do that however. Is there any cli application where I can specify the record to add/remove and send the specific request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is [nsupdate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate) what you're looking for. It can be used to make dynamic changes to suitably configured BIND installations.

```
nsupdate -k /etc/somekeyfile
> server 127.0.0.1 /* address from the controls section of named.conf */
> zone local
> update add usvr.local 86400 cname ubuntuSVR.local
> send /* add the record */
> update delete usvr.local
> send /* delete the record */
```